# Exception throwing - usage

Tags: java, exception

User is asked to select an ID from some given set. I check if that ID exist in my collection, if not I throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and catch it later. Can I actually use that exception for such purpose or is it just a very bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

throwing exceptions does really make sense if you facing really exceptional situation

if the contract of your class suppose than user will never query for a value not in collection, then exception is good. Perhaps IllegalArgumentException or something like this.

otherwise it leads to boilerplate code, and sometimes causes significant performance degradation because of stack unwinding and exception propagation

so it's kind of trade-off whether to throw exception or return some pre-defined value

I'd suggest to return "null" in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If the `ID` is passed as a parameter to a method and you want to check it as part of your pre-post conditions you could either throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or a `RuntimeException`.
`IndexOutOfBounds` does not make sense since it is confusing here. It is an exception raised when you do an access out of bounds

Comment: ID is passed as an argument. Than I do some stuff to find out if it is in a collection, if isn't I throw exception. Now I thought that I can throw that exception only if I know specifically what values are not allowed like null before I execute the function. So in my case I probably can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would throw a checked exception so the calling method is forced to catch it. What you could do is call

```
initCause
```

on the exception and set this as IllegalArgumentException

For example

```
public method(int i) throws MyException {
    if (i < 0) {
       MyException e = new MyException();
       e.initCause(new IllegalArugmentException());
       throw e;
    }
}
```

I would probably also call the correct corectors to pass in messages to that when the exception is thrown it is clear what has happened.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on context, but IMO if you're looking up an ID, a concept not tied to a positional reference, this would be an abuse of that specific exception–perhaps an app-specific ItemNotFound or equivalent.

If your API has a contract that specifies you'll either return a valid object or throw an exception, then throw an exception. Consider also a NullObject pattern instead, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the call works for `23` and the call works for `47`, and nothing's changed in the meantime, then the reason it doesn't work for `35` can't be that an index was out of bounds.